# Icarus verilog: reg show; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment

Tags: system-verilog, iverilog

I am trying to port some Verilog source code to SystemVerilog. This question is specific to Icarus Verilog (tested with 10.3 and 11 providing the same result), since I did not get any errors with tools (e.g. Yosys 0.9.0, Cadence Xcelium 19.09). The issue I have boils down to the following minimal example:

```
module main();
  logic sel;
  wire [31:0] wired;
  logic show;

  initial begin
    $monitor("show = %d", show);

    sel = 1'b1;
    #10;
    sel = 1'b0;
  end

  subout a(.sel_i(sel), .val_o(wired));
  subin  b(.val_i(wired), .out_o(show));
endmodule

module subout(
  input logic sel_i,
  output logic [31:0] val_o
);
  always @(sel_i) begin
    val_o   = 32'b0;

    if (sel_i) begin
      val_o = 32'b101010;
    end
  end
endmodule

module subin(
  input logic [31:0] val_i,
  output logic out_o
);
  assign out_o = val_i[0];
endmodule
```

Apparently, I want to create some `val_o` value in `subout` and wire it up in `main` to pass it to `subin`. `subin` takes the value and returns one bit which is monitored. In other words, a value is passed from one submodule to the other.

The error, I get with `iverilog <file-with-above-content>` is:

```
iverilog_issue.sv:35: error: reg out_o; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
iverilog_issue.sv:15: error: reg show; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
iverilog_issue.sv:15: error: Output port expression must support continuous assignment.
iverilog_issue.sv:15:      : Port 2 (out_o) of subin is connected to show
3 error(s) during elaboration.
```

As far as I understand the situation, it should create one register for `val_o` in `subout` and one register `sel` in `main`. Everything else are just wires. Since, we are using SystemVerilog, I use `logic` and do not specify `wire`/`reg`. To me the conclusion `reg show;` is already incorrect.

1. How does Icarus Verilog conclude `reg show;`?
2. Can you make this example run with iverilog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code runs correctly on [EDAplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/) with an older Icarus 10.0. So my guess is you didn't enable the SystemVerilog flag `-g2012`. By default Icarus runs in Verilog IEEE1364-2005 [[1]](https://iverilog.fandom.com/wiki/Iverilog_Flags); which is the same as setting the flag `-g2005`

Verilog only allows `wire`s to be driven by `assign` statements or output ports.
SystemVerilog relaxed the rule so `reg` and `logic` driven by `assign` statements or output ports so long as that is the only driver. (Bit off topic but, I personally prefer following the stricter Verilog rules because not all tools have strong single source driver checking for `reg` and `logic` driven by `assign` statements or output ports)

Anyway, try this command:

```
iverilog -Wall -g2012 <file-with-above-content>
```